# Subscription of Behavior Subject not working with multiples statements

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I have a very unique problem.

I have created a behavior subject in my service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  baseUrl = `${environment.url}`;

  private appUser: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  setAppUser(user: User) {
    this.appUser.next(user);
  }

  getAppUser() {
    return this.appUser.asObservable();
  }
```

I am calling this Behavior Subject from one of my component.

Now its working and not working under different circumstances.

It works if i subscribe to behavior subject like this

```
    export class AppNavComponent implements OnInit {

      user: User;    

      constructor(private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.authService.getAppUser()
        .subscribe(user => this.user = user)
      }
```

Its not working if i want to execute multiple statements after i subscribe.

```
export class AppNavComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User;
  userCanViewAdmin: boolean = false;


  constructor(private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.getAppUser()
    .subscribe(user => {
      this.user= user;
      this.userCanViewAdmin= this.authService.getUserPermission(user, 'View Admin Page');
    })
  }
```

I really do not understand what i am doing wrong here.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thankyou

Comment: i don't see any error : could you try to create a stackblitz example to see if the error lies somewhere else.

Comment: I just encountered a case where i had an error in my subscribe. It provoque an unsubscribe. So check that your `this.authService.getUserPermission(...)` works properly by putting a breakpoint in your brower console. Depending on how you handle async api call, user might be undefined when you call `getUserPermission`

Comment: Hey  Gérôme Grignon , fixed the issue, thanks for the help

Comment: Thankyou  Quentin Grisel, fixed the issue after reading your comment

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue guys, Dumb on my part to not realize it

The mistake was in my second statement.

```
this.userCanViewAdmin= this.authService.getUserPermission(user, 'View Admin Page');
```

Initally the Behavior Subject sets my user as null and this service is throwing an error because my user is null.

I just need to not call the above service if user is null.

Thankyou Quentin Grisel for giving an idea on where i went wrong.

Thankyou all

Answer (score 0):

as @Quentin said it is very likely subscription callback is having an error.

**Take a look at reproduced example**

```js
const appUser = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject(null);
let user = null;

appUser.asObservable().subscribe(data => {
  user = data;
  // your api call
  throw new Error('Test');
})

appUser.next({
  id: 1,
  username: `test`
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(user);
}, 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the callback was having a issue as you said